# How to Negate in this Jinja if condition?

Tags: python, jinja2

I have this in template:

```
{% if cell %}{% set cell = "b" %}{% endif %}
```

What is contradiction of above conditional?

This not works:

```
{% if !cell %}
```

Comment: Did you tried `{% if not "condition" %}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `not` word, consider following simple example

```
import jinja2
template = jinja2.Template('cell {% if not cell %}negated{% endif %}')
print(template.render(cell=True))  # cell 
print(template.render(cell=False))  # cell negated
```